# Whats the best transaction isolation level can be used for this scenario?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I'm very new to databases and I'm new to postgres as well.
Imagine I'm building a dashboard application which allows the user to edit and update them. Since many users can edit/update a single dashboard, I want to make sure they work with transaction but at the same time scale well.
I have been reading through docs for some days, and I came with my initial plan:

1.Begin transaction and on update statement postgres will acquire a lock on that row (lock is visible till we commit/rollback), so that other user has to wait. But this doesn't solve my problem.

2. Or start the transaction with Repeatable Read, which means each of the user is going to get snapshot of the data accordingly hence they can work with their copy and update them as needed. However I'm wondering whether this could break in say few conditions which I haven't thought about?
   Are there any other ways to handle the same?

Imagine the application is something like the google spreadsheet.

Comment: Read about pessimistic vs optimistic locking, and read the concurrency control chapter of the postgres docs. If you're new to these systems, try to keep it simple and correct.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm new to the system. But the above requirements are possible right with postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend optimistic locking for such a purpose:

- When you `SELECT` a row from a table, remember all its values.
- When you `UPDATE` the row, add a `WHERE` clause that checks if the values are unchanged.
- If no rows were updated, tell the user that the operation failed because there was a concurrent modification.

You would stick with the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level for that.

Answer (score 1):

See these notes I prepared sometime ago on isolation levels:

https://github.com/dmgerman/csc370/blob/master/notes/ch_18_transactions_2.pdf

Most textbooks are very theoretical on what isolation levels are and do not explain it from a practical point of view. My notes are based on postgres and explain not only isolation but also when a query is capable of blocking another due to its isolation level.
The notes also give examples of situations where each isolation level might fail.

In general Read Committed is sufficient for most jobs. Read committed will only yield momentarily incorrect results (for example, an aggregation might consider a value that is being deleted at the moment).

Also, postgres does not implement Read Uncommitted.

Comment: The link is broken